# Ferramenta para enviar comandos à sites de terceiros

Tags: chromium, bot-framework

Tenho um sistema que facilita a vida de alguns clientes, ele deve fazer download e exportação de alguns dados diariamente, assim alguns clientes com pouco conhecimento de informatica não precisam acessar os sistemas e fazer e export de dados.

Pra isso eu conecto no site e utilizo injeção de JavaScript e vou fazendo os clicks e inputs pra exportar os dados.
O problema é que existem alguns sites que possuem bloqueio de JS de terceiros,
por conta disso a pergunta.

**Existe alguma biblioteca ou maneira de conectar a um site e enviar os comandos?**

Não conheço direito mas já ouvi falar do Selenium, mas não sei se funciona melhor que isso.

Obs: Atualmente a minha aplicação trabalha com ChormiumWebBrowser, com ele eu abro o site e utilizo o comando `ExecuteScriptAsync` pra enviar os comandos JS. Já tentei contato com os sites os quais os clientes utilizam, mas como não é um número grande de clientes, fica inviável para eles fazer integração com API ou qualquer integração com nosso sistema.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [Pupeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), biblioteca NodeJS que utiliza o protocolo Devtools para fazer automação, teste ou scraping.

Comment: André, muito obrigado!
Estudei essa ferramenta e consegui implementar, os sistemas que tinham algum bloqueio eu uso o `page.keybord.press()` , então consigo acessar da mesma maneira, valew!